# How to add a event for an HTML note generated by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I added a `taphold` event

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#folder_page", function( event ) {
 $('a.folder_gid').bind('taphold', function(event) {
     //do some thing
  }
}
```

After, on click of a button, I used JavaScript to generate

```
<a class="folder_gid" href="#"></a>
```

But it does not trigger a `taphold` event. How can I get it to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with a dynamic element because of:

> After, on click of a button, I used JavaScript to generate

Use event delegation:

jQuery >= 1.7

```
$(document).on('taphold', 'a.folder_gid', function(event) {
    //do some thing
});
```